# run a task on limited number of hosts in a group using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Team,

basically, goal is to run a task only on N nodes from 1-10 in a hosts group.
trying to see what is the best feasible way to achieve this.. any insights?

here is my try with with hosts parameter but task is getting executed on all hosts.

I have 10 hosts in a group hosts_gpu but I want to run task only on 1-3.

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts_gpu[1:3] test.yml
```

output:

```
all hosts affected
```

expected

```
host1
host2
host3
```

Comment: You can use -l or —limit option to select limited number of hosts within the group. Check this out... https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-l. Also check https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@Mamun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128503/mamun) has already mention you could use `--limit` (or `-l`) option to limit playbook execution to specific hosts.

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory_file playbook.yml --limit "host1:host2:host3"
```

If `hosts_gpu` is a group then you could limit playbook by executing

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory_file playbook.yml --limit "hosts_gpu"
```

Or you could limit execution to the first three hosts in the group using Python list slicing notation.

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory_file playbook.yml --limit "hosts_gpu[0:3]"
```